# Update desktop "show window contents while dragging" setting programatically

Tags: windows, batch-file, settings

One of my programs seems to be changing the Display Properties > Appearance > Effects > Show window contents while dragging setting to off every few hours.

I'm not sure exactly which program, or when it happens.  I have a number of programs that seem like likely culprits - wallpaper rotators, software for multiple monitors, multiple virual desktops and switching, and a few others.

I am just thinking to create a little batch script to run periodically and set the setting back to on.

Does anyone know how to do this in windows?  I'm using xp pro sp3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [RegMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) to find the program that keeps changing your settings. Maybe that's a better start than hacking around it.

Comment: This might work, but given what I mention in my answer (which is that just changing the registry has no effect until you log out and back in), if the culprit is changing the setting programmatically (i.e. NOT changing the registry key directly), monitoring the registry might not report the right thing.  It depends on how RegMon works.

Answer (score 5):

The best option is to do this programmatically using the supported API. i haven't tested this, but it should do the trick:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS, 
                     TRUE,
                     NULL,
                     SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
```

You can use SPI_GETDRAGFULLWINDOWS to see if the the bit has been flipped to avoid unnecessarily triggering a WM_SETTINGCHANGE.

Comment: Tested on Windows 7 x64 - it works! Option takes effect immediately after SystemParametersInfo() call - no need to logoff. (sample app code: https://gist.github.com/neokril/8035995)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, that works great! Is there any chance you could make the application sit in the systray and check-and-fix periodically? Sorry for being so cheeky to ask, but I unfortunately have no C++ skills :(

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple and effective solution to this problem. In Notepad type the following lines :

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop] "DragFullWindows"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\DragFullWindows] "CheckedValue"=dword:00000001 "UncheckedValue"=dword:00000001

Save the file as "Show Window Contents.reg" Double clicking this file and restarting will cure the problem permanently. Post a message if you find this useful.

Aravind Banerjee

Answer (score 1):

It seems the registry setting which controls that preference is HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\DragFullWindows.  You can read more about it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787526(WS.10).aspx).  However, trying it on my own computer does not register the change right away, so a batch script won't do it.  You'll probably have to write a program to manipulate it using SystemParametersInfo().  You can pass it the SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS parameter.  [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(VS.85).aspx) a page explaining it more.  [Here's](http://www.devcity.net/Articles/119/1/vb2005_wallpaper.aspx) a page showing how to call it, albeit not for the same parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's kept in the registry - maybe [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop] - "DragFullWindows"?

It would be easy to flip the registry setting back to "1" every hour or so with a batch file.